# Get a list of entities by list of ids in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

Let's say I have the following schema:

```
type Query {
  user(id: ID!): User
}

type User {
  name: String!
  id: ID!
}
```

If I want to create a query to get user by id, I can easily do that like so:

```
query UserById($id: ID!) {
    user(id: $id) {
        name
        id
    }
}
```

But what if I have a list of ids and I want to get a list / map of users corresponding to this list of ids?

According to the GraphQL specification, it's not recommended to build a query dynamically, so I'd prefer an answer that uses a hard coded query, and enables passing the list of ids as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the allUsers insted of the UserById, and provide the list as a filter.

```
query MyQuery {
  allUsers(filter: {id: {in: ""}}) {
    nodes {
      id
      name
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: But this requires implementing a new resolver for the new field "allUsers" which accepts the filter property, right?
Is there a way to do what I want without changing the schema?

Answer (score 0):

its an old topic and i was facing this scenario too and haven't found an answer. I was able to do this by using the "or" operator and creating a SearchInput which has an array of search objects created from my idList.

See my example code in React Typescript:

```
    const [UserList, SetUserList] = useState<UserObj[]>();
    const idList = [1,2,3,4];
    
    const SearchObjList = idList.map((id) => {
        const searchObj = {
            Id: {
                eq: id
            }
        }
        return searchObj;
    });      
    
    const SearchInput = {
        or: SearchObjList
    }

    const ListByIdList = async () => await client.graphql({
        query: listUsers,
        variables: {filter:SearchInput}
    }).then((data) => {
        SetUserList(data.data.listUsers.items);
    });

    ListByIdList();
```